# Getting 404 when accessing xml file having german characters in name on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, iis-7.5, isapi-rewrite

I have a web application developed in ASP.NET. This app is setup on IIS 6 on windows 2003 server and same application setup on on IIS 7.5 on windows 2008 server. I have some xml files on root of the website having special characters in german i.e. ä,ö etc. When I try to access this file for example:
[http://mytestxml.com/äötest.xml](http://mytestxml.com/%C3%A4%C3%B6test.xml) , it is accessible on IIS 7.5 but when I try to access the same on IIS 6, it comes up with 404 error. Just want to mention that nothing has been done to make it work on IIS 7.5.

Could anyone please suggest on this issue. how it could be resolved? I am really getting troubled with it and need to resolve it asap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on IIS 10 and marking "Allow high-bit characters" in IIS Request Filtering settings fixed it for me.

[image: IIS screenshot]